# import {sub} from "" VS import M from ""

Tags: javascript, import

`export default { HolyClickoutside, ... }       // "holy-components"`

when I import what I need from "holy-components"

```
import HolyComponents from "holy-components"
const { HolyClickoutside } = HolyComponents

console.log(HolyClickoutside)    // {...}
```

is ok

```
import { HolyClickoutside } from "holy-components" 

console.log(HolyClickoutside)    // undefined
```

export destructured object doesn't work， why?

Answer (score 0):

The below line only gets the variable which is exported by default in the "holy-components"

```
import HolyComponents from "holy-components"; // get whatever is exported by default in HolyComponents.
```

The below line only looks for the variable named as HolyClickoutside which can be one of the many named exports in "holy-components".Since no such variable with the particular name exists you would get undefined.

```
import { HolyClickoutside } from "holy-components" // get the variable exported from "holy-components" which has the exact name as HolyClickOutside.
```

The below line looks for the key named HolyClickOutside in an object named HolyComponents.If your variable which was exported by default from "holy-components" has that key, you would get reference to that key.

```
const { HolyClickoutside } = HolyComponents
```

Comment: Thx, but maybe I didn't describe my problem clearly.